# Where I can put the CTA button in a process steps?

Tags: ux-designer, position, process, cta

I'm working with a Process, this process has 5 steps.

I don't know what's the best place to put the "Next" or "Continue" CTA button.

I have 3 options:

- **Top-right on the header**, this options is habitual in a mobile process, but in this case is a desktop process and I think the situation is "blind zone".
- **At the end of the content** , here the problem is than I have scroll, may be the user don't see the CTA.[image]
- **Sticky bottom** I think with a sticky button. In this sticky I show the CTA, the user always see this. This one follows you with the scroll.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Go with the sticky footer.**

It's important to always have the CTA visible.

Check out my question for more information: [Position of 'save' button in content management systems.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108083/position-of-save-button-in-content-management-systems)